# How to list all the code blocks in the current buffer with no #+NAME?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Let's say I have a buffer with some code blocks, but I want to know the location of those code blocks that doesn't have `#+NAME` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Table of contents

1. The answer
2. Minimal working example

## The answer

Use `org-babel-map-src-blocks`.

## Minimal working example

Consider the following Org Mode file

```
01 | * This is the first heading
02 |
03 | #+NAME: foo
04 | #+BEGIN_SRC bash
05 | echo 2
06 | #+END_SRC
07 |
08 | * This is the second heading
09 |
10 | #+BEGIN_SRC bash
11 | echo 1
12 | #+END_SRC
```

You can use the following sexp to show a message whenever a code block with no name is found

```
(org-babel-map-src-blocks nil
  (let ((name (org-element-property :name (org-element-context))))
    (unless name
      (message "Code block with no name found in line %s" (line-number-at-pos))))))
```

If we evaluate the sexp in the Org Mode file, we would get

```
Code block with no name found in line 10
```